# `ionic start` CLI arguments ignored

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

Maybe I'm missing something, but no matter what I try/do, the arguments I provide to `ionic start` in the CLI are not copied to `config.xml` and as a result, I need to manually edit these before running `ionic build` or my project properties are built with the incorrect app name/ID etc.

If I run:

```
ionic start -v -a MyApp -i com.me.myapp IonicApp blank && ionic build
```

Then neither `MyApp` nor `com.me.myapp` are set as my app name/ID respectively.

Am I missing something obvious?

I am using ionic@2.0.0 beta #19, but it occurs on ionic@1.7.14 (latest stable). I am using node@4.3.2 (latest LTS version).

Comment: don't know if this can solve your problem but now is there a new node version (v4.4.0 LTS) and you have the v5.8.0 too which is working good with ionic.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give them a go.